# Table with N associations

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

Suppose I have three tables: `meta_tags`, `users`, `posts`. (just an example)

Users and Posts both could have tags, so my `meta_tags` table could be structured like

```
 meta_tags
   - user_id
   - post_id
   - tag
```

But, I want my `meta_tags` table to be extendable. If I later create an `item` table that could also have a tag, I'd need to adjust my `meta_tag` table with a new `_id` column.

Would it be better to instead format my `meta_tags` table like

```
 meta_tags
   - thing_id
   - thing_type
   - tag
```

so that my query would be

```
 SELECT tag FROM meta_tags WHERE thing_id = 1 AND thing_type = "user";
```

vs

```
 SELECT tag FROM meta_tags WHERE user_id = 1;
```

or, maybe I should have separate tables? `user_tags`, `post_tags`, etc..

I guess my question is...which way is considered best practice? Are their significant performance impacts I should be aware of?

Comment: I think you have it a bit backwards. Tags are entities in themselves, and users, posts, and what-nots have many-to-many relationships with tags.

Answer (score 1):

A way to resolve this would be to put the joining of things with tags into separate tables.  You would have your original tables users, posts, meta-tags and perhaps items.  In addition, you would have user-tags, post-tags, and perhaps item-tags.  The later three tables would only have the keys from the specific type table (e.g. user_id) and the key from the meta-tags table.

This design would also allow you to have other attributes to a tag that apply across all the base tables.

Answer (score -1):

neither

```
base table meta   
- user_id  PK FK user   
- post_id  PK FK post  

tag user table  meta_tags_user_string   
- user_id  PK FK  meta   
- post_id  PK FK  meta     
- tag_ID   PK FK  tag_Def  
- value

tag post table  meta_tags_post_string   
- post_id  PK FK  meta     
- tag_ID   PK FK  tag_Def  
- value
```

You will need separate meta_tags for each value type
e.g. meta_tags_dateTime

Comment: I think you're getting a little caught up on the meta_tag thing. I just used that as an example...my question is about the best way to setup associations. 

Having said that, it seems that you're pushing for a verbose list of _ids on each table...is that correct?

Comment: Answer is only as good as the stated question